# Mysql Insert data to new column with select query

Tags: mysql

I have table structure like this

```
id     start_date      during
1      2018-01-01       2
2      2018-01-02       3
```

And then I would like to add a new column named `end_date` using my query

```
SELECT 'start_date' + INTERVAL ('during')day as 'end_date'
```

then the result become `end_date`

```
end_date
2018-01-03
2018-01-05
```

I would like to add a new column in my table named `end_date` and then insert the data by query before. After I create the new column in my table, I did the query below to insert

```
INSERT INTO table_name(end_date) 
SELECT 'start_date' + INTERVAL ('during')day
```

but the table gonna like this

```
id     start_date      during    end_date
1      2018-01-01       2         null
2      2018-01-02       3         null
3         null          null     2018-01-03 
4         null          null     2018-01-05
```

Comment: What your are describing is `UPDATE` (***not*** `INSERT`).

Comment: What you want is not `INSERT` new rows, but to `UPDATE` existing ones by adding values to a new column...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto thank you, I just realized my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add a new column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`.`new_table` 
ADD COLUMN `end_date` DATE NULL AFTER `during`;
```

Then you can apply your insert:

```
UPDATE table_name SET end_date = start_date + INTERVAL(during) DAY;
```

But if during is always defined from `start_date` and `during` you could create a virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`.`new_table` 
ADD COLUMN `end_date` `end_date` DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    start_date + INTERVAL(during) DAY) VIRTUAL ;
```

Comment: Thanks, i works sir :)
I am stuck because I think the query that should to do is Insert.